# Rails 4 has_many through with where clause deletes multiple associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, where-clause, has-many-through

I have a Project model that has various roles for users. A user may have multiple roles for a project. I have set up the project model associations with a has_many through and a where clause to show the type of role:

```
  has_many :project_user_roles, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :sub_contractors,
           -> { where(project_user_roles: {role: 'SubContractor'}) },
           through: :project_user_roles,
           source: :user

  has_many :consultants,
          -> { where(project_user_roles: {role: 'Consultant'}) },
          through: :project_user_roles,
          source: :user
```

In my project controller, I can update the sub_contractor_ids and consultant_ids. This works fine for adding and deleting roles for all situations except where a user was both a subcontractor AND a consultant, and the consultant role is removed. In this case, ALL roles are removed!. The param hash that is passed is correct:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "project"=>{"sub_contractor_ids"=>["3", ""], "consultant_ids"=>[""] ...
```

, but I can see in the console that the `update_attributes` command results in the SQL:

```
SQL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "project_user_roles" WHERE "project_user_roles"."project_id" = $1 AND "project_user_roles"."user_id" = 3  [["project_id", 3]]
```

which clearly does not account for the where clause in the association that should limit this delete to only those roles that are 'Consultant'.

As I mention above, adding roles is fine I.e. if there are no roles for that user and the same params are passed:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "project"=>{"sub_contractor_ids"=>["3", ""], "consultant_ids"=>[""] ...
```

the resulting SQL includes the role from the where clause:

```
SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "project_user_roles" ("role", "project_id", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["role", "SubContractor"], ["project_id", 3], ["user_id", 6], ["created_at", "2016-06-07 00:32:17.224502"], ["updated_at", "2016-06-07 00:32:17.224502"]]
```

I am either not understanding the where clause correctly or this is not the best way to set this up. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have `dependent: :destroy` on the main association: `project_user_roles` which is the association for all roles... have you tried removing that and putting it on your other two associations instead?

Comment: I tried changing the `dependent: :destroy` to the other associations but it had no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am not 100% sure why this works as it seems equivalent to me, but this is how I have my associations set up now:

```
has_many :consultant_roles,
          -> { where(project_user_roles: {role: 'Consultant'}) },
          class_name: "ProjectUserRole"
has_many :sub_contractor_roles,
          -> { where(project_user_roles: {role: 'SubContractor'}) },
          class_name: "ProjectUserRole"

has_many :main_contractors,
           through: :main_contractor_roles,
           source: :user

has_many :sub_contractors,
           through: :sub_contractor_roles,
           source: :user
```